# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. Installation failed due to: 'Close'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

**i got an error on android studio that says**

`Installation did not succeed.`
`The application could not be installed.`

`List of apks:`
`[0] 'C:\Users\****\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication4\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'`
`Installation failed due to: 'closed'`

---

**i searched and i tried almost every thing but it didn't work for me**

Comment: Have you try clean & rebuild?
Or, if the same error occurs try to disable instant run option from `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run`

Comment: thx for ur help , but i tried to do all of these methods and still not working

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I did not add png to the image name in the Resource file

I solved it by adding .png to the image name. Example: mango.png